# What's the difference between dist-upgrade and upgrading /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --package-names?

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, ansible

What is the difference between upgrading packages using the `dist-upgrade` and upgrading the packages from `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --package-names` ?

The reason I'm asking is, the machine I'm upgrading is running the service `unattended-upgrades` which I believe runs a `apt`-process in the background. When I run `dist-upgrade` (using Ansible) and the `unattended-upgrades` is also trying to upgrade packages I get the error message (obviously) `usr/bin/apt-get dist-upgrade \' failed: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`, but when I try to create a list of the packages that needs to be upgraded using `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --package-names` and upgrade these using the `apt`-module in Ansible I get no errors.

Any ideas?